# Reference for Onsager’s solution of the 2D Ising model

Tags: resource-recommendations, ising-model, spin-models

I am interested in Onsager‘s famous paper “Crystal statistics I” where he derives the solution of the 2D Ising model.

I am reading the original paper, but I search some supplementary material (blog, testbook, paper ect.) where this way (via the Onsager Algebra) of solving the Ising model is explained in other words.

Note that I am NOT interested in the way how Kaufmann solved the model. Even if it is similar.